# How do I keep my escaped double quotes when using sed in bash

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to do a replace where I first escape all double quotes and then I want to use the result of this replace to updated a value. But in the last replace the backslashes are removed, why is this and how do I avoid that?

Example in bash:

```
>TEST_OBJECT='{"val1": "a", "val2": "b"}'

>ESCAPED_OBJ="$(echo $TEST_OBJECT | sed 's/"/\\"/g')"

>echo $ESCAPED_OBJ
{\"val1\": \"a\", \"val2\": \"b\"}

>echo 'value: "_REPLACE_ME"' | sed "s@_REPLACE_ME@$ESCAPED_OBJ@g"
value: "{"val1": "a", "val2": "b"}"
```

I'm expecting this on the last row:

```
value: "{\"val1\": \"a\", \"val2\": \"b\"}"
```

**EDIT**

I realize I presented the issue wrong, the reason why I do it in 2 steps is because the first replace happens in one step and then the second replace happens in a later step. This is part of a github workflow and the last replace actually replaces a string in a different yaml file.

```
sed "s@_REPLACE_ME@$ESCAPED_OBJ@g" > ${{ github.action_path }}/config/job.yml
```

So I don't think I can do the replace in one step, first I need to update the string and then replace a value in another file.

job.yml

```
...
env:
  - name: CUSTOM_DATA_OBJECT
    value: "_REPLACE_ME"
```

I need the value to be escaped so that it doesn't break the yaml.

Comment: With `bash`: `echo "${TEST_OBJECT//\"/\\\"}"`

Comment: Still the same issue, $ echo 'value: "_REPLACE_ME"' | sed "s@_REPLACE_ME@${TEST_OBJECT//\"/\\\"}@g"
value: "{"val1": "a", "val2": "b"}"

Comment: I suspect that you are making it [too complicated](https://izismile.com/2022/12/10/daily_gifdump_weekend_edition_60_gifs-4.html).

Comment: Yes, I agree that on the first look I do it to complicated, but I probably gave a to basic example, sorry for that.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you show a concrete input data and how the output should look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed "s@_REPLACE_ME@${TEST_OBJECT//\"/\\\\\"}@" input_file
...
env:
  - name: CUSTOM_DATA_OBJECT
    value: "{\"val1\": \"a\", \"val2\": \"b\"}"
```

Comment: So basically what is happening here is that the escape chars needs to be escaped, is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe letting [`yq`](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases) take care of the correct escaping for YAML?

```bash
TEST_OBJECT='{"val1": "a", "val2": "b"}' \
    yq eval '.env[0].value = strenv(TEST_OBJECT)' file.yaml
```

```yaml
env:
  - name: CUSTOM_DATA_OBJECT
    value: "{\"val1\": \"a\", \"val2\": \"b\"}"
```

Comment: Yes, I think this also could work, thanks for the input :)